# Django WSGI deployment. No module named '_sqlite3'

Tags: django, mod-wsgi, django-wsgi

I try to deploy Django application under Django 1.8 and Apache mod_wsgi (python 3.4.3, ubuntu 14.04)

I have solved the previous error with import ( [Django WSGI deployment. cannot import name 'SimpleCookie'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30759703/django-wsgi-deployment-cannot-import-name-simplecookie/30761819#30761819) ) but then I meet another one:

```
Error loading either pysqlite2 or sqlite3 modules (tried in that order): No module named '_sqlite3'
```

Here bigger piece of the error log:

```
[Wed Jun 10 18:33:44.021939 2015] [:error] [pid 19282:tid 140071189554944] [client 192.168.1.1:16780]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1448, in exec_module
[Wed Jun 10 18:33:44.021960 2015] [:error] [pid 19282:tid 140071189554944] [client 192.168.1.1:16780]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
[Wed Jun 10 18:33:44.022198 2015] [:error] [pid 19282:tid 140071189554944] [client 192.168.1.1:16780]   File "/var/www/.virtualenvs/cp/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 41, in <module>
[Wed Jun 10 18:33:44.022207 2015] [:error] [pid 19282:tid 140071189554944] [client 192.168.1.1:16780]     class Permission(models.Model):
[Wed Jun 10 18:33:44.022760 2015] [:error] [pid 19282:tid 140071189554944] [client 192.168.1.1:16780]   File "/var/www/.virtualenvs/cp/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 139, in __new__
[Wed Jun 10 18:33:44.022770 2015] [:error] [pid 19282:tid 140071189554944] [client 192.168.1.1:16780]     new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, **kwargs))
[Wed Jun 10 18:33:44.022807 2015] [:error] [pid 19282:tid 140071189554944] [client 192.168.1.1:16780]   File "/var/www/.virtualenvs/cp/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 324, in add_to_class
[Wed Jun 10 18:33:44.022814 2015] [:error] [pid 19282:tid 140071189554944] [client 192.168.1.1:16780]     value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
[Wed Jun 10 18:33:44.023151 2015] [:error] [pid 19282:tid 140071189554944] [client 192.168.1.1:16780]   File "/var/www/.virtualenvs/cp/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 250, in contribute_to_class
[Wed Jun 10 18:33:44.023161 2015] [:error] [pid 19282:tid 140071189554944] [client 192.168.1.1:16780]     self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
[Wed Jun 10 18:33:44.023296 2015] [:error] [pid 19282:tid 140071189554944] [client 192.168.1.1:16780]   File "/var/www/.virtualenvs/cp/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 36, in __getattr__
[Wed Jun 10 18:33:44.023304 2015] [:error] [pid 19282:tid 140071189554944] [client 192.168.1.1:16780]     return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
[Wed Jun 10 18:33:44.023514 2015] [:error] [pid 19282:tid 140071189554944] [client 192.168.1.1:16780]   File "/var/www/.virtualenvs/cp/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 240, in __getitem__
[Wed Jun 10 18:33:44.023558 2015] [:error] [pid 19282:tid 140071189554944] [client 192.168.1.1:16780]     backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
[Wed Jun 10 18:33:44.023603 2015] [:error] [pid 19282:tid 140071189554944] [client 192.168.1.1:16780]   File "/var/www/.virtualenvs/cp/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 111, in load_backend
[Wed Jun 10 18:33:44.023610 2015] [:error] [pid 19282:tid 140071189554944] [client 192.168.1.1:16780]     return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
[Wed Jun 10 18:33:44.023642 2015] [:error] [pid 19282:tid 140071189554944] [client 192.168.1.1:16780]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
[Wed Jun 10 18:33:44.023649 2015] [:error] [pid 19282:tid 140071189554944] [client 192.168.1.1:16780]     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
[Wed Jun 10 18:33:44.023669 2015] [:error] [pid 19282:tid 140071189554944] [client 192.168.1.1:16780]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2231, in _gcd_import
[Wed Jun 10 18:33:44.023690 2015] [:error] [pid 19282:tid 140071189554944] [client 192.168.1.1:16780]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2214, in _find_and_load
[Wed Jun 10 18:33:44.023711 2015] [:error] [pid 19282:tid 140071189554944] [client 192.168.1.1:16780]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2203, in _find_and_load_unlocked
[Wed Jun 10 18:33:44.023732 2015] [:error] [pid 19282:tid 140071189554944] [client 192.168.1.1:16780]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
[Wed Jun 10 18:33:44.023752 2015] [:error] [pid 19282:tid 140071189554944] [client 192.168.1.1:16780]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
[Wed Jun 10 18:33:44.023773 2015] [:error] [pid 19282:tid 140071189554944] [client 192.168.1.1:16780]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1448, in exec_module
[Wed Jun 10 18:33:44.023793 2015] [:error] [pid 19282:tid 140071189554944] [client 192.168.1.1:16780]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
[Wed Jun 10 18:33:44.023826 2015] [:error] [pid 19282:tid 140071189554944] [client 192.168.1.1:16780]   File "/var/www/.virtualenvs/cp/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 36, in <module>
[Wed Jun 10 18:33:44.023833 2015] [:error] [pid 19282:tid 140071189554944] [client 192.168.1.1:16780]     raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading either pysqlite2 or sqlite3 modules (tried in that order): %s" % exc)
[Wed Jun 10 18:33:44.023862 2015] [:error] [pid 19282:tid 140071189554944] [client 192.168.1.1:16780] django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading either pysqlite2 or sqlite3 modules (tried in that order): No module named '_sqlite3'
```

When running development server no errors appear. There is no errors as well when running in python interpreter in virtualenv cp

```
>>>import sqlite3
```

My wsgi.py file is:

```
import os, sys, site

sys.path.insert(0,'/var/www/.virtualenvs/cp/lib/python3.4/site-packages')
sys.path.insert(0,'/var/www/django_projects/cp')
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'mysite.settings'

exec(open("/var/www/.virtualenvs/cp/bin/activate_this.py").read())

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Here is Apache's virtualhost's conf for the site:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName cp.mysite.com
    WSGIDaemonProcess cp user=www-data group=www-data threads=5
    WSGIApplicationGroup cp
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/django_projects/cp/mysite/wsgi.py

    <Directory /var/www/django_projects/cp/mysite>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog    /var/www/errlogs/cperror.log
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: You are doing it in not the best way possible. Inserting something into `sys.path` is an antipattern. So is executing the script with `exec()`. You can make a script (`bash` or whatever) to prepare your enviroment for a server to start. Activate you `venv` and setup settings modul in that file. I can provide an example, if you want.

Comment: I will appreciate this.  I am using what I see in other examples and it is very strange to me that this particular site fails to run.

Comment: I have made a gist for you. Note, that I am not `bash` expert. https://gist.github.com/sobolevn/c99122979654522d4dca

Comment: Spasibo :) I'll check this.

Comment: I expect that you are using a version of mod_wsgi compiled for Python 2, but are running it against Python 3.

Comment: I have this probem recently, but then installed correct mod_wsgi (libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3 under ubuntu)

Comment: @sobolevn What you are suggesting will not really work here as mod_wsgi works by embedding Python into Apache and Apache is then started up by root from the system startup scripts. Although you technically could modify the system startup scripts to have them try to activate a Python virtual environment, it is a security risk as that would have to be done as root, which opens up possibilities for root code execution if someone were to fiddle with the virtual environment.

Comment: Although there are better ways than updating sys.path, it is not an anti pattern as you would suggest and is one of a number of valid techniques you would use here. Similarly using exec() is not an issue, although rather than read the file contents in and use exec(), the virtualenv documentation says to use execfile() on the file name direct.

Comment: That all said, the preferred way is to use the python-home and python-path options to WSGIDaemonProcess directive. See http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2014/09/using-python-virtual-environments-with.html and http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2014/09/python-module-search-path-and-modwsgi.html In this case, I agree with @DanielRoseman though, in that mod_wsgi is likely compiled for a different Python version that the virtual environment. You can't mix them.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton, I use exec instead of execfile since the latter has been removed form Python 3.X.               I have double checked that libapache2-mod-wsgi is not installed on my system - only libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3, which is for Python 3

Comment: Are you sure libapache2-mod-wsgi-py isn't for Python 3.3. Check by trying: http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/CheckingYourInstallation#Python_Shared_Library http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/CheckingYourInstallation#Python_Installation_In_Use

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton, the answer of the server (your second link) is " sys.version = '3.4.0 ......" So it users default system Python3. while in virtualenv cp I use 3.4.3

Comment: I have checked my resulting sys.pah: ['/var/www/django_projects/cp', '/var/www/.virtualenvs/cp/lib/python3.4/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python3.4', '/usr/local/lib/python3.4/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/local/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages']  It includes folders from my virtualenv as well as from systmem's python3 . Is it correct?

Comment: If you have a separate Python 3.4.3 installation under /usr/local that is different to the system Python, you are going to have to rebuild mod_wsgi against it. Quite likely the Python 3.4.3 installation hasn't been configured with compatible set of build time options and so mixing installations like that isn't going to work. In general, mixing different installations is a bad idea. Take heed of that first link and ensure that ldd shows the correct Python library being picked up. If not, use LD_RUN_PATH at compile time to define where it is as explained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finaly, after making a debug with a help of simple wsgi.py (thanks to @GrahamDumpleton for the [link](https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/CheckingYourInstallation#Python_Installation_In_Use)), I've found that my resulting sys.path is not too clean.

So I have manually changed sys.path in wsgi.py taking it from python started in virtualenv cp and then added project directory to this list at the begining in wsgi.py:

```
import os, sys

virtual_env = '/var/www/.virtualenvs/cp'    
sys.path=['%s/lib/python34.zip' % (virtual_env,), 
          '%s/lib/python3.4' % (virtual_env,), 
          '%s/lib/python3.4/plat-linux' % (virtual_env,), 
          '%s/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload' % (virtual_env,), 
          '%s/lib/python3.4/site-packages' % (virtual_env,),
          #'/var/www/python/3.4.3/lib/python3.4', 

          ]
sys.path.insert(0,'/var/www/django_projects/cp')

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'mysite.settings'

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Possibly this is not the "best practice" solution, but it does remove magic functions and easy to understand and repeat for new user like me :)